# Extract the first match and the word after the second match (until reaching comma) only if we match the two words we are looking for

Tags: python, regex

So I have the following text:

*Hipotecas:*

*Nos encontramos con varias hipotecas. La primera es una hipoteca que tiene 30.000€ dinero a favor de Banco XYZ, esta hipoteca...*

I'm trying to extract the words "**hipoteca**" and the **word following the sentence "a favor de" until reaching the comma**. So my extraction would be: **"hipoteca"** and **"Banco XYZ"**.

The point is that:

- "hipoteca" must appear before "a favor de".
- In case one of the two does not appear, I do not want to extract anything.
- In case "hipoteca" appears multiple times, just extract one match.

I am able to extract both separately but I'm wondering if is it possible to do that with just one regular expression.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your code you managed to write so far..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working regex would be

```
r"\..+(hipoteca).+a favor de (.+),"
```

**Explanation**

`\.` Matches a `.` literally, so you ensure that you are in a new sentence

`.+` Arbitrary characters at the beginning of the sentence allowed

`(hipoteca)` First matching group

`.+` Arbitrary characters

`a favor de` This text segment must be within the sentece

`(.+)` Second matching group

`,` The second matching group is ended by a comma

**Usage**

You can search your text with following code snippet only using one search:

```
text = "Nos encontramos con varias hipotecas. La primera es una hipoteca que tiene 30.000€ dinero a favor de Banco XYZ, esta hipoteca"

pattern = r"\..+(hipoteca).+a favor de (.+),"

m = re.search(pattern, text)

print(m.group(1))
# hipteca

print(m.group(2))
# Banco XYZ
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
(hipotecas).+a favor de (.+),
```

You can see it here https://regex101.com/r/kKsdCb/1

Comment: That one matches the very first occurrence of hipoteca which is not in the same sentence.

Comment: Should be `(hipoteca ).+a favor de (.+),`